# Number of solutions of $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d}=1$

Tags: inequality

Find the number of solutions $(a,b,c,d)$ such that $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d}=1$,$\enspace$$a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{N}$ and $a<b<c<d$.

> I have got a solution:
> $$\frac{1}{2}\cdot(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{6})+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{12}=1$$
> But how to get other solutions.
> **I received total $6$ solutions from Wolfram Alpha.**

Comment: It appears that you are limiting "solutions" to rational numbers.  Is this the case?

Comment: I think you should take $a,b,c,d$ as roots of a 4 degree and then use $S_3$ and $abcd$.

Answer (score 5):

1. Show $a\le4$.
2. Run through various possible values of $a$ and $b$.
3. To solve ${1\over c}+{1\over d}={1\over4}$ for example,
   $${1\over c}+{1\over d}={1\over4}\\
   4d+4c=cd\\
   (c-4)(d-4)=16$$
   Now just run through the factors of 16.

Comment: To the editor: I was actually trying to solve for $a\le b\le c\le d$ so your edit would have been correct but works better as a comment.